# Beautify debugged arrays of Smarty

Tags: php, debugging, smarty

I am debugging Smarty Arrays by the way **{$oItem|@print_r}**. The result is often terrible to read. Is there a way to beautify it? I need to read the Array [cArtNr].

Looks like here and much is cut off:

> Array ( [0] => Konfiggruppe Object ( [kKonfiggruppe:protected] => 11
>   [cBildPfad:protected] => 11.jpg [nMin:protected] => 1 [nMax:protected]
>   => 1 [nTyp:protected] => 2 [nSort:protected] => 0 [cKommentar] => [oSprache] => Konfiggruppesprache Object ( [kKonfiggruppe:protected]
>   => 11 [kSprache:protected] => 1 [cName:protected] => Netzteil [cBeschreibung:protected] => )[oItem_arr] => Array ( [0] => Konfigitem
>   Object ( [kKonfigitem:protected] => 37 [kArtikel:protected] => 1213
>   [nPosTyp:protected] => 0 [kKonfiggruppe:protected] => 11
>   [bSelektiert:protected] => 0 [bEmpfohlen:protected] => 1
>   [bPreis:protected] => 1 [bName:protected] => 0 [bRabatt:protected] =>
>   1 [bZuschlag:protected] => 0 [bIgnoreMultiplier:protected] => 0
>   [fMin:protected] => 1 [fMax:protected] => 1 [fInitial:protected] => 1
>   [oSprache:protected] => Konfigitemsprache Object (
>   [kKonfigitem:protected] => 37 [kSprache:protected] => 1
>   [cName:protected] => Original Raspberry Pi Netzteil 5V - 2,5A
>   [cBeschreibung:protected] => [cKurzBeschreibung:protected] =>
>   )[oPreis:protected] => Konfigitempreis Object (
>   [kKonfigitem:protected] => 37 [kKundengruppe:protected] => 1
>   [kSteuerklasse:protected] => 1 [fPreis:protected] => -10
>   [nTyp:protected] => 1 )[oArtikel:protected] => Artikel Object (
>   [kArtikel] => 1213 [kHersteller] => 6 [kLieferstatus] => 0
>   [kSteuerklasse] => 1 [kEinheit] => 0 [kVersandklasse] => 1
>   [kStueckliste] => 0 [kMassEinheit] => 0 [kGrundpreisEinheit] => 0
>   [kWarengruppe] => 1 [nLiefertageWennAusverkauft] => 0
>   [nAutomatischeLiefertageberechnung] => 0 [nBearbeitungszeit] => 0
>   [fLagerbestand] => 10 [fMindestbestellmenge] => 1 [fPackeinheit] =>
>   1.0000 [fAbnahmeintervall] => 0 [fGewicht] => 0.2 [fUVP] => 0.00 [fUVPBrutto] => 0.00 [fVPEWert] => 0.0000 [fZulauf] => 0 [fMassMenge]
>   => 0 [fGrundpreisMenge] => 0 [fBreite] => 0 [fHoehe] => 0 [fLaenge] => 0 [cName] => Raspberry Pi 5V 2,5A Original Netzteil [cSeo] =>
>   Raspberry-Pi-5V-25A-Original-Netzteil [cBeschreibung] => Orginal
>   Netzteil mit 5V und 2,5A Micro USB Stecker für alle Raspberry Pi's
>       [cAnmerkung] => [cArtNr] => SER00000 [cURL] => Raspberry-Pi-5V-25A-Original-Netzteil [cURLFull] =>
>   Raspberry-Pi-5V-25A-Original-Netzteil [cVPE] => N [cVPEEinheit] =>
>   [cSuchbegriffe] => [cTeilbar] => N [cBarcode] => 640522710911
>   [cLagerBeachten] => Y [cLagerKleinerNull] => N [cLagerVariation] => N
>   [cKurzBeschreibung] => Orginal Netzteil mit 5V und 2,5A Micro USB
>   Stecker für alle Raspberry Pi's [cMwstVersandText] => Endpreis*, zzgl.
>   Versand [cLieferstatus] => [cVorschaubild] =>
>   media/image/product/1213/sm/raspberry-pi-5v-25a-original-netzteil.jpg
>   [cHerstellerMetaTitle] => [cHerstellerMetaKeywords] =>
>   [cHerstellerMetaDescription] => [cHerstellerBeschreibung] => Our goal
>   to help the world learn & share electronics and computer programming
>   continues with our new line of products made just for the Raspberry
>   Pi®. What is the Raspberry Pi® ? A low-cost ARM GNU/Linux box.

Comment: wrap it in `<pre>` tags, or, `header("Content-Type: text/plain");` if you don't mind all the page html being shown as text

Comment: Thanks! Please give an Answer to vote you (not a comment).

Comment: :) cheers brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

wrap your output in `<pre>` tags

or

`header("Content-Type: text/plain");` if you don't mind the entire page being shown as text